# Images from iOS camera are sent rotated in web application

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, jpeg, exif, uiimageorientation

I am building an application in HTML5 for iPad to upload a picture to a server. When I click an input file element like this:

```
<input id='fileup' type='file' accept='image/*' name='upf' onchange='abv();'/>
```

It gives the possibility to either take a picture from the device camera or to upload from existing ones. However, when taking a picture, the resulting image is rotated based on the orientation of the device at the moment the photo is taken. What I want to do is to figure out the orientation of the captured image and try to rotate it on the server-side.

Notice that I do not have access to any iOS tools or frameworks, since this application is totally web-based.

Then, is there any information regarding the orientation of the picture that I can either access on the client or on the server-side, such that I would be able to rotate the images into the proper position? I have heard of EXIF data, but I am unsure on how to access it, and if it would give me the required information.

I am using python on the server-side, but a solution in C/C++ would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this application running in a browser or is it installed using Phonegap/Titanium or other frameworks?

Comment: It is running in a browser, Safari browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using python on the server-side

So you can use [jpegtran-cffi](https://github.com/jbaiter/jpegtran-cffi) Python package that provides the ability to perform EXIF *auto-transform*:

```
# jpegtran can transform the image automatically according to the EXIF
# orientation tag
photo = JPEGImage(blob=requests.get("http://example.com/photo.jpg").content)
print photo.exif_orientation  # "6" (= 270°)
print photo.width, photo.height # "4320 3240"
corrected = photo.exif_autotransform()
print corrected.exif_orientation  # "1" (= "normal")
print corrected.width, corrected.height  # "3240 4320"
```

*Note: extracted from the README.*

---

As an alternative there is also a convenient command-line tool called [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) that you can use for the same purpose:

```
#    Remove EXIF orientation
#    i.e. rotate the image accordingly and reset the orientation
#    flag to 1 (default, i.e. origin = TopLeft)
#    WARNING: the image file is overwritten!
#    NOTE: it also works with a wildcard: jhead -autorot *.jpg
jhead -autorot myimage.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing it on the client, but this seems like a perfectly viable solution. Cheers.